# What's the difference between 天国 and 高天原?

Tags: word-choice

I think the difference may be the heaven of other religions versus the heaven of Shintou, but I'm not 100% on it either way. Am I right, or is there still something I'm missing on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally 天国 refers to the Christian heaven (while 地獄 can refer to both, the Christian and Buddhism hell). Both words are frequently used in everyday language (「天国だね」、「地獄行き」). 高天原 refers to the 神道 concept and is not really used in everyday language.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense with what I've been reading then. I wonder why the words for heaven are different, yet the one for hell is nearly the same. Huh.
Either way, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

Kind of, but there's controversy and we ourselves don't know what it exactly is either. Since shinto myth is a mystified form of our ancestor's history, it's probably a place in north Kyushu. It's of course not a place above the sky where you go after death.

Comment: What I've been reading describes it as a sort of floating island in the sky, but that makes a lot of sense too.